# Who has the authority to decide that a tevilah (immersion) in a mikvah was invalid after the fact?

Tags: halacha, mistakes, mikvah-ritual-bath, chatzitzah

Can a woman who goes to the mikvah, and realized afterwards that she had barriers on her body, render her own tevilah invalid? Or is it considered valid after the fact even if, had she known, she would have removed the barrier before immersing?  (After all, the mikvah attendant was there and didn't object.)

Assuming the immersion might not have been valid, can she judge for herself or does she need to consult a rabbi or maybe the mikvah attendant?

Comment: If she knows she had a barrier then why _wouldn't_ the immersion be invalidated?

Comment: I was wondering if she needs to get an authority figure to confirm it.

Comment: To confirm *what*? That she had the barrier on her? How would the "authority" figure know what was on her skin?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Mr. Psychnerd.  Do you have any reason to think this should be any different than any other case of knowing the facts?  Please feel free to [edit] any assumptions that go in to your question.

Comment: @DoubleAA (and YeZ, but I can't ping you in this comment) There's a priori the possibility that, as sort of with _tzaraas_ in _halacha_ and as with all of American law, the facts are considered separately from the law, and she can decide for herself what was on her skin but cannot decide what the law therefore is.

Comment: @msh210 Yes but why would that be different before or after dipping?

Comment: @msh210 I'm fine with that.  But why is that a question here more than, say, if you find a hole in a lung, or if you find out that what you thought was mayonnaise that you put on your hamburger was really sour cream?  Is there a reason that specifically in this case the OP has reason to wonder if rabbinic consultation is necessary more than in any other fact-based case?  If so, that should be in the question.

Comment: @YeZ, I agree completely.